# Fast likelihood evaluation for Gaussian distribution with diagonal plus low rank covariance

Tags: normal-distribution, likelihood, factor-analysis, approximation

Let's assume the likelihood

$$
y \sim\mathcal N_p(0, \Sigma + \Lambda\Lambda^\top)
$$
where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal $p \times p$ matrix and $\Lambda$ is a $p \times d$ matrix with $d \ll p$.

What is the fastest way to compute the Gaussian density at one specific value $y$?
Naive implementations would still scale cubically in $p$ since one needs to invert and compute the determinant of $\Sigma + \Lambda \Lambda^\top)$. Are there some more efficient ways to go?

Comment: Of what use would computing a likelihood for a single value $y$ be?  Likelihoods acquire meaning only when compared, implying you would be computing for at least two distinct values, right?  Or perhaps for the same value of $y$ but varying values of $\Lambda$? Considerations of how many calculations you need to make and how their inputs might be related are crucial for designing and recommending algorithms.

Comment: @whuber, my use case is actually different, because I actually need $\mathcal N_p(\mu, \sigma + \Lambda \Delta \Lambda^\top)$ where $\Delta$ is a dense $d \times d$ matrix that is observation-specific (I have a hierarchical Bayesian model). The computation of such likelihoods are useful for efficient MCMC sampling. The question is general enough so that others could benefit as well and jld's answer below gave me the necessary building blocks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\L}{\Lambda}$We need to be able to efficiently evaluate $y^T(\Sigma + \L\L^T)^{-1} y$ and $\det (\Sigma + \L\L^T)$. The standard approach here is to use the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) and [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma#Generalization) to change our hard operations from being on $p\times p$ matrices to being on $d\times d$ matrices.

The Woodbury matrix identity gives us
$$
(\Sigma + \L\L^T)^{-1} = \Sigma^{-1} - \Sigma^{-1}\L(I + \L^T \Sigma^{-1} \L)^{-1}\L^T\Sigma^{-1}.
$$
$\Sigma$ is diagonal so $\Sigma^{-1}$ takes $O(p)$ operations. $\Sigma^{-1} \L$ then is scaling each row of $\Lambda$ by the corresponding element of $\Sigma^{-1}$ so this takes $O(dp)$ time. $\L^T (\Sigma^{-1} \L)$ then naively takes $O(d^2 p)$, so the time taken to get to $I + \L^T \Sigma^{-1} \L$ is $O(d^2p)$. This is a $d\times d$ matrix now so inversion is naively $O(d^3)$ so we're at $O(d^3 + d^2p)$.

$\Sigma^{-1}\L(I + \L^T \Sigma^{-1} \L)^{-1}$ is $O(d^2p)$ as well, but then we end up with a $(p\times d) (d\times p)$ matrix multiplication which is $O(p^2d)$, so in all we're at $O(d^3 + d^2p + dp^2)$ and $d \ll p$ means this is effectively $O(dp^2)$ which is better than the $O(p^3)$ we'd have with a direct naive inversion.

For the determinant, the matrix determinant lemma gives us
$$
\det(\Sigma + \L\L^T) = \det(I + \L^T \Sigma^{-1} \L)\det \Sigma.
$$
$\det \Sigma$ is just $O(p)$, and we can do $I + \L^T \Sigma^{-1} \L$ in $O(d^2p)$ as we saw above. We now need the determinant of this matrix which is $d\times d$ so we're at $O(d^3 + d^2 p)$ which is effectively $O(d^2 p)$ given $d \ll p$.

All together we can do this in $O(dp^2)$ operations (and it would be a little faster if we did this for real since matrix multiplication and inversion can be done a little faster than the naive way).

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I'm not mistaken, we don't actually need to compute the full inverse but to evaluate the quadratic form. So if we multiply $\Lambda^T \Sigma^{-1} y$ (which can be done in O(dp) right?) we should be able to further reduce the cost to be linear in $p$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @mariob6 good point, yeah, if we really do just need it for this particular $y$